# Calling a service twice with two different parameters in same method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I am developing a web application using *Spring mvc* i am calling a service twice with two different parameters for getting two different lists to be bound to 2 `model.addattribute` but i am able to get either 1 list only.

I am new to java spring development so forgive if this is a very basic question. I am using codemaster entity (Table) for storing all type related options used in the application in one place

the code is as below :

```
@RequestMapping("/processmass")
public String processmass(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("processmassList", processmasService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("pmastypList",codemasterService.findbyrectype("8"));
    model.addAttribute("yesnoList", codemasterService.findbyrectype("9"));
    return "processmass";
}
```

Comment: you can pass the parameter like **/processmass/{type}** and in your inside a method based on type get your list in model.addAttribute

Comment: Please consider this as closed. May be some issue in build that time but now it is working. both lists are available on the jsp and am able to bind it to both select options. Thanks all.